# Apple Push Notifications (APNS) with .Net C#

Tags: objective-c

I am using web service in .net for iPhone push notification . Its working fine from local server and system.
But its not working at Live Server,At live server it is throwing exception "An Internal error occured!" .
Since my server does not support SSL and may be its not connecting to Port = 2195 
to *gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com*.... Can someone please let me know how this issue can be fixed??? or any other Alternative to access gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com without using 
port 2195( i.e without SSL as my server does not support SSl).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Urban Airship? http://urbanairship.com/

Getting Push notification to work can be a bit tricky, and urbanairship helps you with logs and a well documented API.